# Getting SharePoint to return a usable .ics file

Tags: list, email

How do I get SharePoint to generate the correct iCal format?

I used the directions on several sites [Specifically this one](http://virtualducttape.com/generating-an-ical-ics-file-from-a-sharepoint-calendar-list-item/) to get Sharpoint to create an .ics file and hyperlink so that when users click the title of the meeting the .ics file opens and they can add it to their calendar.

I created the following fields:Title, Description, StartDate, EndDate, Location

Here's my code:

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href='.../teams/lscsp-cat20/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={2119CB58-D934-4A21-B5C4-7B7D406D897D}&CacheControl=1&ID="&[Item ID]&"&Using=event.ics'>"&Title&"</a>")
```

Unfortunately I get an error with the .ics file.
[image]

When I look at the .ics code it is as follows, which is not the standard, and acceptable iCalendar format. How do I get SharePoint to generate the correct format?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//SharePoint MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID;TYPE=SharePoint:10
DTSTART:
LOCATION;ENCODING=8BIT;CHARSET=utf-8:
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:4
DTSTAMP:20150407T201940Z
SUMMARY;ENCODING=8BIT;CHARSET=utf-8:Using Excel for funn
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=8BIT;CHARSET=utf-8:This is a simple descriptin of the session.​
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: The DTSTART doesn't seem to have a value and there is no DTEND. Does that matter?

Comment: The only way I was able to do a proper iCal was to roll my own XML within a Nintex workflow.

Comment: @PirateEric is there an alternate solution that doesn't require Nintex workflow? In my situation we are not able to add additional software to the SharePoint farm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in earlier versions of SP (2007 and 2010) there was an actual calendar list (type 106) that came prepopulated with "properly" named columns.

owssvr.dll is looking for columns with internal names of **EventDate** and **EndDate**. So create columns with those names. (You can change the display names later if you want.)

Found the answers in these posts and comments.

- http://binduchinnasamy.blogspot.com/2012/07/generate-outlook-ics-file-from.html
- https://ameyakawale.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/email-a-calendarappointment-link-using-sharepoint-workflow/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. That was just what I needed to get my list to work.