# How can I generate a custom ICS that includes attendees?

Tags: 2007

I have a custom list that has some workflow involved and once an item has been approved it should generate (for the end user) an outlook invitation to send that includes attendees, some item information in the body, etc...

I realize you can generate a [basic ICS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137525/getting-sharepoint-to-return-a-usable-ics-file) that includes the title, begin date and end date, but again I'd like to include some additional information.

How feasible is it to generate this file in SharePoint for the user as a download?